# how to plot a solution of differential equation, which is a piecewise function?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, symbolic, piecewise

I want to plot the solution of a differential equation, which involves a piecewise function, the rectangle function `UnitBox`. As a result, the solution computed by mathematica is also a piecewise function.

```
a[z_, L_] := UnitBox[(z/L + 0.5)]
V''[z] + k^2 V[z] == 0.5 k^2 a[z, 1]^2
sol = DSolve[V''[z] + k^2 V[z] == 0.5 k^2 a[z, 1]^2, V[z], z]
V[z] /. sol[[1]] /. {k -> 1, C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 2}
Plot[V[z], {z, -5, 5}]
```

But when I try to plot the solution it is not showing anything. In fact `V[3]` doesn't give me the value of the function. What have I done wrong and how to plot the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably see from Mathematica's Front End that the `V[z]` which you are attempting to plot has a blue color. This indicates that no values have been assigned to `V[z]` in the kernel. If there's nothing stored in `V[z]`, it cannot be plotted. Use an intermediate symbol such as `myFunc`:

```
a[z_, L_] := UnitBox[(z/L + 0.5)]
V''[z] + k^2 V[z] == 0.5 k^2 a[z, 1]^2
sol = DSolve[V''[z] + k^2 V[z] == 0.5 k^2 a[z, 1]^2, V[z], z]
myFunc = V[z] /. sol[[1]] /. {k -> 1, C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 2}
Plot[myFunc, {z, -5, 5}]
```

> [image]